# Catching the mole problem best winning strategy

Tags: combinatorics, puzzle, game-theory

The problem is:

There is a mole and n holes named with numbers $1, 2, 3, \ldots, n-1, n$. The mole can start from any hole and each day it can move only from a hole to a consecutive hole. So if the mole is at hole $3$ the next day it can move to hole $2$ or hole $4$. To catch the mole you place a trap in a single hole everyday and each day you can change the position of the trap to anywhere you like.

There is a winning strategy for catching the mole and I proved it does catch the mole eventually. If there are $n$ holes and $n$ is odd place the trap in the sequence 
$$2, 3, 4, 5, \ldots, n-2, n-1, 2, 3, 4, 5, \ldots, n-2, n-1$$
and if $n$ is even place the trap in the sequence 
$$2, 3, 4, 5, \ldots, n-2, n-1, 1, 2, 3, 4, \ldots, n-2, n-1\text{.}$$
So for odd $n$ $2(n-2)$ days are required and for even $n$ $2(n-2)+1$ days are required with this method.

How can I show that this is the minimum number of days required to guarantee catching the mole?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is a classic. The diagram in the accepted answer [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/455/why-does-this-solution-guarantee-that-the-prince-knocks-on-the-right-door-to-fin) gives an excellent illustration of the capture method.